# ASIHTTP equivalent for OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, networking, file-upload

Im looking to upload xml files to a php server that range from 1mb to 50mb. As far as I can tell ASIHTTP was the code to use back in the day but Im looking for a newer framework to work with. 
The ASIHTTP website recommended AFNetworking, but I was wondering if there were any other good ones out there I should look into. Im VERY new to cocoa programming and have started off learning with ARC enable so something compatible with that would be ideal also.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now AFNetworking is the best choice. I've used it and it's pretty good. I recommend it!

Comment: I started dabbling around with MKNetworkKit but I will take a look at AFNetworking also thanks

Comment: Ive started using AFNetworking. I have posted a question here if you dont mind helping out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422379/uploading-a-file-with-post-using-afnetworking

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at recommendations that are a few years old suggesting you use a third party library, you might consider taking a second look at what the OS itself provides. NSURLConnection still isn't the best solution for everyone, but it's improved much over the last few iOS & OS X releases.